# интеграция MetaTrader5 python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

#устанавливаем подключение к терминалу
if not mt5.initialize():
     print("initialize() failed")
     mt5.shutdown()

# получаем символ и таймфрейм активного графика
symbol_info = mt5.symbol_info(mt5.chart_symbol())#mt5.ChartSymbol()
timeframe = mt5.TIMEFRAME_CURRENT
```

ошибка в следующем:

```
mt5.chart_symbol()
AttributeError: module 'MetaTrader5' has no attribute 'chart_symbol'
```

так же пробовал и `mt5.ChartSymbol()`, все тщетно...подскажите что куда и где можно найти?

Comment: Вы бы написали, что хотите получить в результате своего кода, откуда вы вообще взяли этот chart_symbol (ведь в документации (https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/python_metatrader5) про него ни слова.

Comment: хочу получить символ и таймфрейм активного графика,а  chart_simbol подсказала gpt,  есть ChartSymbol() но без изминений,так же нет атрибута

Comment: получается функционал пакета не полный?это https://docs.mql4.com/ru/mql5_language/mql5_functions/mql5_chart_operations значит не будет функционировать?